# Perl/OOP: How to create object of "Class B" in constructor of "Class A"

Tags: perl, oop, object, object-composition

I have Class A with following constructor:

```
sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;

    return bless(\%args, $class);
}
```

I have another class, LWP::UserAgent, which I want to use in my Class A.
I could solve the problem by doing this:

```
ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;

    return bless(\%args, $class);
}
```

But in this case I will have 1 object of UserAgent, but I want a *unique* object for each instance of my Class A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you need to construct that object as an attribute

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;

    return bless { %args, lwp => LWP::UserAgent->new }, $class;
}
```

and now every object of class A will have for attribute `lwp` its own `LWP::UserAgent` object.

I would of course expect that in reality this is written out nicely with all requisite error checking.

---

And I guess better call the attribute `ua` (instead of `lwp` above), for User-Agent.

Comment: Could you please tell me following:
Is "{ %args, lwp => LWP::UserAGent->new }" the same as following code?
```$args{lwp} = LWP::UserAgent->new;
return bless(\%args, $class);
```

Comment: @Nazar Yes, and doing `\%args` is a (bit) more efficient than copying it with `{ %args }`.  However, this is done _once_ per object's lifetime.  Just how many objects does that code create?  I'd write it out nicely -- i think you really have to, in order to check the user input (the `%args`).

Comment: I don't think I will create more than 2-3 objects. But just to be flexible I decided to move this logic out of class to instance. 
I use Params::ValidationCompiler to validate user* input but not lwp object. Since lwp object is internal and I don't want user to modify it on constructor step.

Comment: @Nazar Ah, OK, you have (even proper!) validation in place.  (I don't know the module but I can expect that it's good.)

Comment: Yep :) Thanks again for your help!